# JSON output of a <br />(escaped) interpreted the browser not correctly

Tags: javascript, html, json, browser

I have a json file like this

```
[
  {
    "titel": "Das \"Hexenbödele\" bei Lengstein",
    "vorspann": "Sage vom Ritten, übertragen von P. Beda Weber. Im Wald oberhalb von Lengstein und von diesem Ort nicht weit entfernt liegt das \"Hexenbödele\", eine kleine Lichtung, in deren Mitte eine einzelne Lärche hoch aufragt. Diese Lärche ist mit einem auffälligen \"Hexenbesen\" und zudem mit einem Kruzifix geschmückt. Hier trafen sich nachts vor alten Zeiten häufig die Hexen der ganzen Umgegend und hielten mit dem Teufel wüste Gelage<br \/>",
    "downloadlink1": "http://theweburl.com/files/content/557263_42961_1_0/das-hexenbödele-bei-lengstein-weber-483.pdf",
    "downloadlink2": "http://theweburl.com/files/content/557263_42962_1_0/l-hexenbödele-di-longomoso.pdf",
    "downloadlink3": "http://theweburl.com/files/content/557263_42963_1_0/the-hexenbödele-at-lengstein.pdf"
  }
]
```

If I'm outputting that code in my browser(Chrome and FF) and the browser interpreted the `<br \/>` like a normal break line.

I've escaped all correctly..

Has any one here a idea how to fix that?

Thanks in advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape html with entities (http://unicode.e-workers.de/entities.php).

The `<br />` would look like this: `&lt;br /&gt;`

Answer (score 1):

It's because browser interprets the `<br>` tag when it encounters `"<br"` itself.

You should try `&lt;br /&gt;` to display `<br />` in the browser.